# How to test for the entity closest to the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am making a map and I need to be able to test for the CLOSEST entity to the player, is this possible with /testfor yet? /execute @e[type=entity name here]  ~ ~ ~ /testfor @p will test for the player closest to an entity, instead of the closest entity to the player. So how do I achieve this? Is it even possible? It's kinda like how if you have Steve and Alex next to a command block with the command /testfor @p will find Steve if Steve is closest and same with Alex, just entities instead of people and relative to me, not a command bock.

Answer (score 2):

> /execute as @e[sort=nearest] run <'whatever'>

for 1.13

Comment: This still works as of 1.17

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft selectors work on some very strange principles. `@a`, `@p`, and `@r` used to be the only way to select players, while now they are just a shorthand.

Using the count selector, we can select up to `n` entities in order of range. Because of this, `@p` is equivalent to `@a[c=1]`. We can use the same principle to target the nearest entity using `@e[c=1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (It will only test for mobs and not players nearby):

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[type=!Player]
```

This is what I think you mean in the question, but I don't know. !Player is case sensitive, so be careful.

Comment: Isn't it `type=!Player`?

Comment: Ok so you know how when u type in the chst /testfor @p it will tell you the closest player, i just want it to test for the closest entity. And a command to put in the command block so the command block can run the command for the player

Comment: ok now that this works, is it possible to do, lets say, "save" that entity, so it teleports me to the nearest entity then saves that entity

Comment: also , is it possible for me to do let say, if the closest entity is a pig say hi, and if the closest entity is a wither, do that, and so on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the future, I recommend checking the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/) before posting a question here.

This is entirely possible using the [`execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) command and target selector [variables](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_variables) and [arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).

### Executing commands at the player

The `execute` command executes commands on an entity.
The `@p` selector selects a single player.
The `name=` argument only selects entities with a specific name.
So `execute @p[name=<your username here>] ~ ~ ~ <command>` will run `<command>` at your location.

### `testfor` the nearest entity.

The `@e` selector finds entities of any type.
The `c=` argument selects a certain count. If this number is positive, it will select these in order from closest to furthest. `c=1` will select the nearest entity.
The `rm=` argument selects only entities outside of a radius. If this is set to 0, it will select any entity that is *not* the executing entity.
So `testfor @e[c=1,rm=0]` would find the nearest entity to the executor of the command.

### Putting it together

So, the first command will execute the second command at the player, meaning your finished command is

> /execute @p[name=] ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[c=1,rm=0]

### Closing comments/notes

As far as using `testfor` goes, I'd recommend against it. The [scoreboard](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard) is almost always more useful, since you can use things like `tag` to mark the entity you found.